# C# Winforms, assigning parent to new child object, other than instantiating form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I have an MDI container with two child forms. We've been taught (and the MSDN documentation only gives the example) to use the keyword 'this', which assumes that the child object in question is being created from the MDI container itself.

If I were creating the object in the MDI container, this would be correct:

```
Form_Child2 child = new Form_Child2(textBox1.Text);
child.MdiParent = this;
child.Show();
```

Instead, I'm trying to do something more like:

```
Form_Child2 child = new Form_Child2(textBox1.Text);
child.MdiParent = Form_Parent;
child.Show();
```

However, this throws an error saying that "Form_Parent" is a type and cannot be used as a variable. I think I vaguely understand what it's getting at, but it's not clear. I've tried studying up on keyword 'this' a bit as well, but still stuck.

Comment: Where you creating new child form?

Comment: Fabio, I was attempting to create the new child within the partial class (which I'm not entirely sure what means yet) script of my first child form, in the context of an event handler for a button click. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Understanding the difference between types and objects is super-duper important if you want to be a C# programmer.  Yes, big problem here, an instance of Form_Parent is required here, you cannot use the type name.

There is only ever *one* instance of the MDI parent window.  Which is something you can take advantage of, you can add a static property to the parent class.  Make that look like this:

```
public partial class Form_Parent : Form {

    public static Form_Parent Instance { get; private set; }

    public Form_Parent() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
    }
    // etc..
}
```

Now it is very simple:

```
Form_Child2 child = new Form_Child2(textBox1.Text);
child.MdiParent = Form_Parent.Instance;
child.Show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes this instantiation process was what I didn't know how to do. This is interesting. I'm certain I need to study much more on accessibility and the nature of objects and instances. I see that you created the instance of Form_Parent as an auto-implemented property, and while we were taught the basics of this, I've yet to fully understand it. So, in other words, I see it works, I vaguely see HOW it works, but I'm not clear .... why it works. But for now this is excellent and has helped me immensely -- thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to set a `Type` as a Parent

You need to instantiate the type before setting it as a Parent :

```
Form_Parent parent = new Form_Parent();
Form_Child2 child = new Form_Child2(textBox1.Text);
child.MdiParent = parent;
child.Show();
```

Of course, if your parent is already created, you need to set the Parent to that instance and not create a new one.

If you do not knew what Instance, Object and Class meant, i would recommand you to read about [Object Oriented Programmation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes I was trying to assign the new child to the original, extant, parent form.